# Divide two lists of matrices where the ith matrix element in one list is divided by the ith matrix element in the second list

Tags: r, arrays, list, matrix

I have two lists of matrices. Here is an example of their structure:

```
list1<- list(structure(c(1, 2, 7, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 4, 1, 3, 2, 3, 4, 
6, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3), .Dim = c(7L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(c("lepA", 
"lepB", "lepC", "lepD", "lepE", "lepF", "lepG"), NULL)), structure(c(1, 
3, 7, 1, 3, 2, 3, 4, 6, 4, 1, 3, 3, 3), .Dim = c(7L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(
c("lepA", "lepB", "lepC", "lepD", "lepE", "lepF", "lepG"), 
NULL)), structure(c(5, 8, 7, 1, 3, 3, 3), .Dim = c(7L, 1L
), .Dimnames = list(c("lepA", "lepB", "lepC", "lepD", "lepE", 
"lepF", "lepG"), NULL)))

list2<-list(structure(c(6, 1, 51, 13, 15, 0, 0, 0, 6, 50, 13, 15, 6, 
5, 5, 9, 0, 0, 0, 7, 5), .Dim = c(7L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(c("lepA", 
"lepB", "lepC", "lepD", "lepE", "lepF", "lepG"), NULL)), structure(c(6, 
7, 51, 13, 15, 6, 5, 5, 9, 50, 13, 15, 7, 5), .Dim = c(7L, 2L
), .Dimnames = list(c("lepA", "lepB", "lepC", "lepD", "lepE", 
"lepF", "lepG"), NULL)), structure(c(11, 10, 51, 13, 15, 7, 5
), .Dim = c(7L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(c("lepA", "lepB", "lepC", 
"lepD", "lepE", "lepF", "lepG"), NULL)))
```

I need to divide each element of each matrix in a list with the corresponding element in the matching matrix in the second list. It's as though the two lists of matrices should be one list of arrays and the dividend is calculated for each array element. The result would be:

```
list<- list(list1[[1]]/list2[[1]], list1[[2]]/list2[[2]], list1[[3]]/list2[[3]])
```

I tried:

```
list1/list2
```

Comment: `mapply("/",list1,list2)`

Comment: As a coding-style recommendation (request): *please* don't use the *function* `list` right next to the *variables* named `list`, `list1`, and `list2`. It's certainly syntactically legal, but dang it's hard on my eyes.

Comment: what syntax do you use when working with lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Map` :

```
Map(`/`, list1, list2)

#[[1]]
#           [,1]       [,2]      [,3]
#lepA 0.16666667        NaN 0.8000000
#lepB 2.00000000 0.16666667 0.6666667
#lepC 0.13725490 0.08000000       NaN
#lepD 0.07692308 0.07692308       NaN
#lepE 0.20000000 0.20000000       NaN
#lepF        NaN 0.33333333 0.4285714
#lepG        NaN 0.60000000 0.6000000

#[[2]]
#           [,1]       [,2]
#lepA 0.16666667 0.80000000
#lepB 0.42857143 0.66666667
#lepC 0.13725490 0.08000000
#lepD 0.07692308 0.07692308
#lepE 0.20000000 0.20000000
#lepF 0.33333333 0.42857143
#lepG 0.60000000 0.60000000

#[[3]]
#           [,1]
#lepA 0.45454545
#lepB 0.80000000
#lepC 0.13725490
#lepD 0.07692308
#lepE 0.20000000
#lepF 0.42857143
#lepG 0.60000000
```

Or `map2` in `purrr`

```
purrr::map2(list1, list2, `/`)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `seq_along` with `lapply`

```
lapply(seq_along(list1), function(i) list1[[i]]/list2[[i]])
```